# Set a x position to a SKSpriteNode

Tags: ios, swift, skspritenode

Hi iam developing a simple brick game. The game look like this.

[image]

At the bottom of this image you can see a paddle(yellow color bar). On touchesBegan i want to get the x position of the touch and move the paddle to that x position.

I tried but am getting the error.

> 2016-12-21 14:35:50.540 BrickOut[1347:38411] SKUtil.m: MGGetBoolAnswer
>   is not available in the simulator.
>
> X Location :  (95.0, 670.33332824707)
>
> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value (lldb)

**Swift Code**

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

    var ball:SKSpriteNode!
    var paddle:SKSpriteNode!

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        ball = self.childNode(withName: "Ball") as! SKSpriteNode!
        paddle = self.childNode(withName: "Paddle") as! SKSpriteNode!


        ball.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 50, dy: 50))
        let border = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom: (view.scene?.frame)!)
        border.friction = 0
        self.physicsBody=border

    }



    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

        for touch in touches{
            let touchLocation = touch.location(in: self.view)
            print("X Location : ", touchLocation)
            paddle.position.x = touchLocation.x

        }
    }

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        for touch in touches{

            let touchLocation = touch.location(in: self.view)
            print("X Location moved: ", touchLocation)
            paddle.position.x = touchLocation.x

        }
    }

}
```

Can some one help me to fix this. I want to change the paddle x position to the touched x position.

Comment: `if let ball = self.childNode(withName: "//Ball") as? SKSpriteNode {
            ball.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: 50, dy: 50))
        }`

Comment: although you are missing the sprite node in your GameScene file

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can ignore this

> 2016-12-21 14:35:50.540 BrickOut[1347:38411] SKUtil.m: MGGetBoolAnswer is not available in the simulator.

Next, in these lines

```
ball = self.childNode(withName: "Ball") as! SKSpriteNode!
paddle = self.childNode(withName: "Paddle") as! SKSpriteNode!
```

you should cast to `SKSpriteNode` not `SKSpriteNode!`

### Now run again and... you just got a crash exactly when the scene is loaded right?

It means that in your `sks` you didn't put an `SKSpriteNode` named `Ball` and/or another `SKSpriteNode` named `Paddle`